# How to change a boolean value in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, boolean

I'm trying to make a button with two functions:

```
function bigfont()
{var font_is_small = true
if (font_is_small = true)
{document.getElementById('one').className=
document.getElementById('one').className.replace("font1","font2");
document.getElementById('two').className=
document.getElementById('two').className.replace("font1","font2");
document.getElementById('three').className=
document.getElementById('three').className.replace("font1","font2");
document.getElementById('four').className=
document.getElementById('four').className.replace("font3","font4"); 
font_is_small = true;}
if(font_is_small = false)
{document.getElementById('one').className=
document.getElementById('one').className.replace("font2","font1");
document.getElementById('two').className=
document.getElementById('two').className.replace("font2","font1");
document.getElementById('three').className=
document.getElementById('three').className.replace("font2","font1");
document.getElementById('four').className=
document.getElementById('four').className.replace("font4","font3");
font_is_small = true;}}
```

But the variable doesn't change. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Change `if (font_is_small = true)` to `if (font_is_small === true)`

Comment: equality comparator is `==` or `===` in javaScript

Comment: Also see this SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: Or just leave it out. `if (font_is_small) { ... }` and `if (!font_is_small) { ... }` are actually much more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change a boolean to its opposite value you can use negation (`!`), for example `x = !x` means "set `x` to `false` if it's truthy or to `true` if it's falsy".
If you want the function to toggle between small and big font the simplest way is to place te variable outside of the function:
http://jsfiddle.net/zvoeLu9p/

```
var font_is_small = true;
function bigfont()
{
    font_is_small = !font_is_small; // switch the boolean
    if (font_is_small){ // no need for == true
        document.body.className=
        document.body.className.replace("font1","font2");
    }
     else { // no need for if condition
        document.body.className=
        document.body.className.replace("font2","font1");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

But you have the variable font_is_small in true all the time you have to change it to false in your code you don't do this.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's where your variable is created and assigned, your equivalence in the if (= means assign) and you are setting it to true in BOTH if statements. ... try ...

```
var font_is_small = true;
```

Based on your usage, font_is_small should be a global, not passed in or created inside the function.

```
function bigfont() {
  if (font_is_small === true) {
    document.getElementById('one').className="font2":
    document.getElementById('two').className="font2":
    document.getElementById('three').className="font2":
    document.getElementById('four').className="font2":
    font_is_small = false;
  }
  if(font_is_small === false) {
    document.getElementById('one').className="font1":
    document.getElementById('two').className="font1":
    document.getElementById('three').className="font1":
    document.getElementById('four').className="font1":
    font_is_small = true;
  }
}
```

Also, the replace wasn't doing anything significant ... I figured out the two line formatting after fixing this ... this assignment is simpler and clearer.